# Safety of set_len operation on Vec, with predefined capacity

Tags: vector, rust

Is it safe to call `set_len` on `Vec` that has declared capacity? Like this:

```
let vec = unsafe {
    let temp = Vec::with_capacity(N);
    temp.set_len(N);
    temp
}
```

I need my Vector to be of size N before any elements are to be added.

Looking at docs:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#capacity-and-reallocation
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.set_len

I'm a bit confused. Docs say that `with_capacity` doesn't change length and `set_len` says that caller must insure vector has proper length. So is this safe?

The reason I need this is because I was looking for a way to declare a mutable buffer (`&mut [T]`) of size N and `Vec` seems to fit the bill the best. I just wanted to avoid having my types implement Clone that `vec![0;n]` would bring.

Comment: No, it's not safe in general!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs are just a little ambiguously stated. The wording could be better. Your code example is as "safe" as the following stack-equivalent:

```
let mut arr: [T; N] = mem::uninitialized();
```

Which means that as long as you write to an element of the array before reading it you are fine. If you read before writing, you open the door to [nasal demons](http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) and memory unsafety.

> I just wanted to avoid clone that vec![0;n] would bring.

llvm will optimize this to a single memset.

Comment: It's not so much I'm avoid instructions as to not having to constrain my types to be `Clone`, which `vec!` macro requires.

Answer (score 1):

If by "I need my Vector to be of size N" you mean you need memory to be allocated for 10 elements, `with_capacity` is already doing that.

If you mean you want to have a vector with length 10 (not sure why you would, though...) you need to initialize it with an initial value.
i.e.:

```
let mut temp: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(10); // allocate room in memory for 
                                            // 10 elements. The vector has 
                                            // initial capacity 10, length will be the 
                                            // number of elements you push into it
                                            // (initially 0)
v.push(1); // now length is 1, capacity still 10
```

vs

```
let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![0; 10]; // create a vector with 10 elements
                                   // initialized to 0. You can mutate
                                   // those in place later.
                                   // At this point, length = capacity = 10

v[0] = 1; // mutating first element to 1.
          // length and capacity are both still 10
```

Comment: Well I also wanted to guarantee that any `&mut [T]` produced from `Vec` would have correct length and won't cause out of bounds errors.

Comment: @DanielFath sorry, I had not seen the last part of your question.

Comment: @DanielFath I'm still not sure if I understand your question... unless you use unsafe code somewhere, references in Rust already maintain the information about the length of the vec (so you should have no out of bound errors)

Comment: Here is what I was doing http://is.gd/U0VXtU Without `set_len` the thing would panic. And I needed the offsets.

Comment: @DanielFath well, you ARE doing something unsafe... :) In that case AFAIK the set_length "forces" the destination vector to be seen as already containing 10 elements, as ptr::copy apparently iterates on length, not capacity

Comment: From what @ker said its not unsafe unless I go outside what was copied, i.e. if I read uninitialized memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81204/discussion-between-daniel-fath-and-paolo-falabella).